# Redirecting to a different page after post ajax call made to django view

Tags: javascript, ajax, django

I have been trying to get this simple piece of code working fine, but still am not able to. Have gone through multiple other links. Am not able to figure out what is that I doing wrong. I have a javascript function `submitData()` which just has to make an ajax `post` call to a django view. The django view basically just has to check if the request is a `post`, if it is, it has to redirect to another page.

My javascript function `submitData()` is as below and have also added the part of code which takes care of sending the `csrf` token along with the `post` request.

```
function submitData()
    {
      $.post('/loggedin/',{"fname":"name1","lname":"name2"},function(data){
        alert("Back from views.py");

      });
    }

$(function () {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: { "X-CSRFToken": getCookie("csrftoken") }
        });
    });

function getCookie(c_name)
    {
        if (document.cookie.length > 0)
        {
            c_start = document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");
            if (c_start != -1)
            {
                c_start = c_start + c_name.length + 1;
                c_end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", c_start);
                if (c_end == -1) c_end = document.cookie.length;
                return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start,c_end));
            }
        }
        return "";
     }
```

In my `views.py`, I have the following code,

```
def loggedin(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        fname = request.POST.get('fname')
        print fname #The code comes here, prints the fname
        args = {}
        args.update(csrf(request))
        return render_to_response('loggedout.html',args,context_instance=RequestContext(request)) #This does not redirect to a different page
    print "outside in loggedin"
    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    return render_to_response('loggedin.html',args, RequestContext(request))
```

When the `post` call is made, the fname is printed but the redirection that is suppose to happen by the function `render_to_response()` is not happening. Instead the `post` call is returned and the alert statement in the `post` call "Back from views.py" is alerted. I am not sure on what I am missing out.

Comment: Please show code of `render_to_response`

Comment: The `loggedin()` function in `views.py` has `render_to_response`(). I am just using the `render_to_response()` function given by django's django.shortcuts library. Code as in?

Comment: There is no redirection going on here at all.

Answer (score 2):

You can redirect after `post` has successfully completed using javascript.

```
function submitData()
    {
      $.post('/loggedin/',{"fname":"name1","lname":"name2"},function(data){
        alert("Back from views.py");
        window.location = 'yourpage.hmtl'
      });
    }
```

Or if you are sending page name in response you can use `data` to redirect to page.

Comment: But i think it is only sending response to your ajax call.

Comment: This way works... but is it not possible to do the same from the django view itself?

Comment: I don't think so as you are sending `ajax` call and ajax is supposed to behave like that.